I want to integrate gtest to my c project
Hi i want to integrate gtest to my c project with is cross-platfom and uses cmake for building .

gtest can run on projects that are cross-platform (linux/win/mac/android)?

when adding gtest to the project , will i have to change some of my source code beside cmake files ?

Any forum that i can use/help when encountering issue when integrating the gtest to my project ? and also a good documentation for integrating the gtest on a cross-platform project using cmake ?


Thanks
running ctest to run all gtest tests


gtest can run on projects that are cross-platform (linux/win/mac/android)?

Yes. See the list of supported platforms here.

when adding gtest to the project , will i have to change some of my source code beside cmake files ?

Normally, gtest does not require any changes to your source code.

Any forum that i can use/help when encountering issue when integrating the gtest to my project ? and also a good documentation for integrating the gtest on a cross-platform project using cmake ?


There is a themed google group.
The easiest way to integrate gtest is to use the FetchContent CMake module.
See docs.


To include it in your project you can use FetchContent. The documentation even uses the GTest repository in their example, so you can't go wrong there.
Other than that, have a look at the offical documentation from Google.
